# Convert datetime string in list to datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

Line 84 in lstToDt() method, I tried to convert 'i' which takes a string datetime from list to datetime object but:

- when I use `datetime.datetime.strftime(i,"format")` an error comes that i is a string object and not datetime.datetime.
- When I use `datetime.datetime.strptime(i,"format")` an error comes that i is a `datetime.datetime` and not string.

Code :

```
def lstToDt(lt):      # Converts list string elements into Dates
    for i in lt:
        i = datetime.datetime.strftime(i,"%Y-%m-%d")
        lt.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(i,"%Y-%m-%d"))
    return lt

Errors :
i = datetime.datetime.strftime(i,"%Y-%m-%d")
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'

lt.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(i,"%Y-%m-%d"))
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime
```

What is happening? Can anyone help please?

Comment: You are usually using `strftime()` by creating a `datetime`, `date` or `time` instance and calling it from there: `datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 23, 59, 0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score 1):

You have passed string value to strptime, that is not acceptable for python,

```
def lstToDt(lt):      # Converts list string elements into Dates
    for i in lt:
        j = datetime.datetime.strptime(i,"%Y-%m-%d")
        lt.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(j,"%Y-%m-%d"))
    return lt
```

This should work!
Hope this helps!